# How to handle users re-asking a question with more info/code the 2nd time

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529627/radgridview-multiselecting-by-mouseclick-without-ctrl-button/24531206#24531206) and then the user's followup/re-ask [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532045/telerik-radgridview-change-selecting-rows).

The 2nd question actually has code in it now and is a little more clear what they're asking, although it poses two questions in one.  What's the best way to handle this situation?

In general, when users re-ask a question but the 2nd is more detailed or just over-all better, should the first be closed?

Comment: Typically I'd say merge the questions, but in this particular case I don't either one of those questions are of particularly good quality and should probably both be closed.

Comment: Close the second as a duplicate of his first one, and give him a hint he should ***edit*** his question instead of re-asking after a superficial polish. Otherwise he'll dig himself a really big hole very fast.